# Scheduling Test runs in ADO pipeline with YML

Tags: cron, gitlab-ci.yml

New to ADO and pipeline. I am trying to schedule to execute test runs in ADO pipeline with YML and running into an issue with defining the Tests (e.g. Smoke test or Regression Tests) and the environment.
Here is the sample of schedule I have in yml with other steps to be executed.

schedules:

- cron: '0 19 * * *'
  displayName: The name to be displayed
  branches:
  include:

  - master
    testType: Regression Tests
    env_name: FOR

When I push the changes to repo, I get an error:

/pipelines/run_automated_tests.yml: Unexpected value

Any help here will be highly appreciated please.

It works fine if I remove the variables for testType and env_name. It takes the value from default